# OAuth2 CallBack URL

Tags: android, callbackurl

I am doing OAuth2 authentication on Android. I get a "java.util.NoSuchElementException" error when trying to use the authorization code further down the line. After testing it seems that the call is correct, but I get nothing back..

My callback uri is set in the Settings Page, the Activity and the Manifest (see below). According to me it is not working because I am not in production.

One advice I received is to "set up your application as webapp", but it is not clear to me what steps I exactly have to take. Any advice?

Intent Filter set in the Manifest File.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <data android:scheme="https://fibi22cj69"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/> </intent-
    filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like that:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="yourcallback.com"
        android:scheme="oauth" />
</intent-filter>
```

And in the client, set the callback url to `oauth://yourcallback.com`

Comment: Thanks! Callback url in the client like this   oauth: //ht tps ://xxx     .com   ?   Don't mind the spaces, otherwise I cannot put it here..

Comment: @NielsVanwingh you can replace the scheme with https if you want, just make sure you put the url in the `android:host` attribute in the manifest.

Comment: Ok, thanks, seems ok, now I still need to find a usable url to work in Testing environment.. So this could work in Production..